# margin-top ребенка - сдвигает родителя - почему?

Tags: html, css

Вставляю блок, и даю ему margin-top: 50px - и он сдвигает родителя body в данном случае. Почему так происходит?

Если же дать padding-top: - тогда ок все

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.logo-bg {
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-bg">
  <a href="#" class="logo">Logotype</a>
</div>
```

Comment: так же было у меня, так и не нашел ответа, единственное,  что спасло ситуацию, задал проблемному элнменту в твоем случае это -  "logo-bg"     display: inline-block   не пришу ответом, потому что не знаю ответа на вопрос "почему"....  тоже бы хотел бы знать точный ответ

Comment: @Air да решает вопрос padding-top, вместо margin-top, но интересно то почему)

Comment: А вот и ответ)))))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Это называется Выпадание внешних отступов (margin'ов)

Если внутри родительского блока расположить блок и задать ему отступ сверху, то внутренний блок прижмется к верхнему краю родительского, а у родительского элемента появится отступ сверху. Т.е. верхний отступ внутреннего элемента «выпадает» из родительского элемента.

Если у родительского элемента тоже был задан внешний отступ, то выберется максимальный отступ между собственным и «выпавшим».
Чтобы избавиться от эффекта выпадания, можно задать родительскому элементу внутренний отступ (паддинг) сверху или добавить рамку сверху (border-top: 1px solid transparent).

Внешние и внутренние отступы всегда складываются.

Comment: Кстати вот хорошая статья об использовании внешних и внутренних отступов
https://habrahabr.ru/post/340420/

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой. Теперь знаю, как её решить))

Answer (score 3):

Похоже на своеобразное ["схлопывание".](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin)
Еще [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/skhlopyvayushchiesya-otstupy) есть более подробная инфа.
В данном примере достаточно заменить у `body` `outline` на `border` или задать `padding`.