# margin-top дочернего элемента- действует на родителя?

Tags: css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #f6f2f2;
}

.content {
  max-width: 1248px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: #313030;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav .active {
  background-color: #ff3f40;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ff3f40;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-left: -4px
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="nav-bar center">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="/" class="active">HOME</a>
          <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
          <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
          <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="sec">
        <div class="inf">
          <h1></h1>
          <h4></h4>
          <button></button>
        </div>
        <div class="video"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Собственно в чем проблема. Когда я задаю фон для wrapper, то он уползает вместе с nav-bar на 30px...
Как от этого избавиться ?

[image: ((]

Comment: Уберит у  `nav-bar` `margin-top: 30px;`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [margin-top ребенка - сдвигает родителя - почему?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734001/margin-top-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #f6f2f2;
}

.content {
  max-width: 1248px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
padding-top:30px; //----------------write!!!!
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-bar {
  background-color: #313030;
  width: 100%;
  //margin-top: 30px; ------------ delete!!!!
}

.nav .active {
  background-color: #ff3f40;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ff3f40;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-left: -4px
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="nav-bar center">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="/" class="active">HOME</a>
          <a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
          <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
          <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="sec">
        <div class="inf">
          <h1></h1>
          <h4></h4>
          <button></button>
        </div>
        <div class="video"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```