# Как убрать лишний отступ сверху у сайта?

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.первыйбл {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://www.1zoom.me/big2/719/321582-svetik.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="первыйбл">
  <h1>Загаловок</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: h1{margin-top: 0}

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [margin-top ребенка - сдвигает родителя - почему?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734001/margin-top-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83)

Comment: @Air только у него для `первыйбл` и для `h1` не задан `margin` по идее ни чего не должно быть у него

Comment: Максим должно быть, потому что по умолчанию у `h1` есть отступы.

Comment: @Zicrael да точно ...проверил есть

Comment: @Zicrael  хотя если обнулиться для всех элементов то нету : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/errOLe?editors=1100

Comment: Ну если обнулить то понятно, а вот изначально в чистом `html` есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin-top:0` для `h1`.

```css
body {
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.первыйбл {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://www.1zoom.me/big2/719/321582-svetik.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="первыйбл">
  <h1>Загаловок</h1>

</div>
```

Или использовать [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) (линк на файл гита)

Comment: да там вообще не для `h1`  а для всех элементов обнулиться надо т.е написать так *{margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;} а h1 не сдвигать а задать верхгий внутренний отступ так : padding-top:20px;

Comment: А ещё лучше просто `normalize` поставить и все.

Comment: тоже верно ... и так тоже можно

Answer (score 4):

Использовал комментарий **`@DiDex`** + поправил немного твой код.

Вместо 100vh, попробуй задать странице `html,body { height:100%}` и тогда высоту блоков ты можешь не только в `vh` выражать, но и в `%`

Так же, может изменить `background-size` на `cover`?

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  }
  
.первыйбл{
  height: 100%;
    background : url(https://www.askwallpapers.com/pic/201502/2560x1600/askwallpapers.com-30818.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1{
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>тест</title>
    <!--Начало подключение стилей-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/главная(стили).css">
    <!--Конец подключение стилей-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="первыйбл">
        <h1>Загаловок</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: в следующий раз, редактируйте ответ вместо клонирования, пожалуйста. Система может ограничить вам возможность размещать ответы при большой доле удалённых.

Comment: @vp_arth система сама продублировала. Поэтому я поспешил удалить дубликат

Comment: Хм, разница во времени публикации 2 минуты. Вероятно стоит разместить отчёт об ошибке на [meta]

Comment: Это выход из ситуации, но ни как не решение вопроса...

Answer (score 0):

Запомните, изначально всему сайт задаётся отступ с верху и с левой, если не ошибаюсь 5px. Чтобы убрать эти самые отступы пишется код:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

"Звездочка" Означает что все теги изначально не будут иметь отступ.
Уже потом вы можете конкретному классу дать padding/margin и это будет работать.

Также не мало важно сразу для всех ссылок отключать декорацию с помощью свойства text-decoration: none;

Код:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Это означает что изначально у ссылок не будет подчеркивания, а вы сами сможете задать конкретным ссылкам свойства которые вам нравятся