# Сбивается отступ от внешнего блока если убрать границу (html-вёрстка)

Tags: html

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 700px;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать margin-отступ от внешнего блока .outer. Если прописать границу блоку .outer, то всё работает корректно. Но если границу (border) убрать, то блок .outer сам сдвигается вниз до уровня .inner. Не могу понять, в чём причина такого поведения. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/340420/

Comment: По данному вопросу нашёл дополнительную информацию вот тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734001/margin-top-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83

Comment: Подошёл вариант с использованием padding-top для отступа между вложенными блоками.
Вариант с использованием прозрачной (transparent) границы тоже работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант - оставьте границу, но сделайте её прозрачной (вместо black напишите transparent):

```css
.outer {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 700px;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я такой вариант пробовал. Он работает. Но только в таком случае появляется "щель" в 1px в верхней части, через которую видно фон.

Comment: @Михаил, ну да, Вы же не написали в условии, что ещё фон будет. Тогда такой вариант не подходит, конечно