# margin-top ребенка отталкивает родителя, а не отталкивается сам

Tags: html, css

Почему в данном примере если задать margin-top списку, то отталкивается весь div.block, а не сам список отталкивается от верхней границы div.block?

https://jsfiddle.net/ru2t80s3/

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.block {
  background-image: url(https://s.ill.in.ua/i/news/630x373/440/440217.jpg);
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    Текст Текст Текс Текст
    <br> Текст Текст Текс Текст
    <br> Текст Текст Текс Текст
  </div>
</div>
```

В то же время у меня есть аналогичный (как мне кажется) пример, где все отталкивается так, как я ожидаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это стандартное поведение. Этот вопрос часто встречается и много чего уже написано например здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element и здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734001/margin-top-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.block {
  background-image: url(https://s.ill.in.ua/i/news/630x373/440/440217.jpg);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    Текст Текст Текс Текст
    <br>
    Текст Текст Текс Текст
    <br>
    Текст Текст Текс Текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему в моем примере (который на картинке) все работает так, как ожидается?

Comment: отредактировал как в примере